# cleaner url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, opencart

Ok so i am using [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) which is an open source shopping cart. I installed it [here](http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/) the problem is that when you click on anything and I mean anything the url goes from this

```
http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/
```

to

```
http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=18
```

so ultimately what is happening is that

```
/index.php?route=CONTROLLER/VIEW
```

which makes sense but the url is ugly and I was wondering if there was a way in htaccess that i can just make all the pages lose this middle portion and have it something like this

```
http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/product/category&path=18
```

ideas anyone....thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should rather see the documentation of OpenCart (framework) for enable "user friendly URL" routing. Rather than change .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
# Turn on URL re-writing
RewriteEngine On

# Clean URLs
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$   /index.php?route=$1/$2&path=$3    [NC,L]
```

Then you would access it with urls like:

`http://example.com/category/product/354`

Note, however, that this is a rather broad rule which will match anyfolder/anyfolder/45 as well as known category/product names, so, you may want to tweak it to limit just to known categories.

Comment: thanks again for your post...one thing though, how do you tweak it to say from only products, category and account